# How to execute a Qt app on macOS Terminal?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, terminal, qt-creator

When I execute the following on QtCreator I do see the `hello world` printed on the screen. However if I exectue it from Terminal by doing `open project.app`, then there is no output. Why? Perhaps I'm not executing it the right way, so how to execute a Qt app on macOS Terminal?

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "hello world";
    return a.exec();
}
```

project.pro

```
QT += core 
CONFIG += c++11 console app_bundle
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I tried the following but looks like there might be other problems going on:

```
$ ./project.app/Contents/MacOS/project 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /Users/user/QtProjecs/project/./project.app/Contents/MacOS/project
  Reason: Incompatible library version: project requires version 5.13.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.7.0
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS/X .app folders hide their executable in the Contents/MacOS subdirectory, so if you want to execute the executable directly and see its output in Terminal, you'd run it like this:

```
 ./project.app/Contents/MacOS/project
```

Comment: I tried that, appended result to the quesion. Any idea on how should I proceed?

Comment: Sounds like your program is built with one version of Qt, but your shell environment is trying to load Qt shared libraries from a different version.  Try running “otool -L ./project.app/Contrnts/MacOS/project” to see which shared library files the app is trying to link to; perhaps you can remove the old Qt version from your machine so they don’t interfere.